# Eclipse cannot resolve enum in the same namespace?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've run accorss a really weird issue, in eclipse I've got a codebase I've been working on for a couple of weeks and it's working fine. I did an svn update and all of a sudden one of my classes doesn't compile because it can't resolve an enum which is in the same namespace to a type.

I've checked the Java version and I'm running under Java 6 so enums should be supported.

Also it worked up till yesterday and now it doesn't.

Has anyone else seen this kind of behaviour? I've reloaded eclipse but beyond that I dont know where to start diagnosing it.

Comment: Is this Eclipse-only, or does maven/ant/javac fail as well?

Comment: I've only tried in eclipse I'll try using javac and get back to you.

Comment: Maybe your project file got damaged? It lost track of the JDK?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Exact error is "Step cannot be resolved to a type" where Step is an enum in the same package as the class thats using it.

Comment: I met the same issue with you and tried to change the build path. The issue disappeared. But I'm still not quite sure where the problem is. It's really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unloaded the project and reloaded it and it just works... No idea what the origianl issue was...

Answer (score 3):

If it does say "Step cannot be resolved to a type", just try and clean the project (Project -> Clean). Eclipse gets confused sometimes, and a clean usually helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had this recently. Turned out that someone had committed some jars that conflicted (had a previous build in) and put on the build path. Check recent commits to see if that's the problem, or to see what could have caused it.

However I would definitely do a build clean first within Eclipse, and see if ANT/Maven is affected (you do have such build scripts I assume).

Answer (score 0):

Weird idea, but could it be that eclipse is trying to compile your class using a 1.4.2 compiler and isn't recognizing the enum?